# Algebraic k-form, potential mistake in notes

Tags: linear-algebra

In my lecture notes which introduces the algebraic $k$-form notation, I am not sure if the function makes sense.

An algebraic $k$-form on $V$ is a function on $V^k$ that is linear in each argument and which changes sign if two grguments are interchanged. That is , letting $a$ denote an algebraic $k$-form, we have that

$a:V^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}; (v_{(1)},...,v_{(k)})\mapsto a(v_{(1)},...,v_{(k)})$

Surely we would have to have $a:V^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ or we could have $(v_{(1)},...,v_{(k)})\mapsto a(v_{(1)}\cdot\cdot\cdot v_{(k)})$.

Since the map is to one dimension ($\mathbb{R}$), how can the image be $k$-dimensions.

Is this a typo or the correct notation?

Comment: because of $a(v_{(1)},...,v_{(k)})$

Comment: Why is the "or we could have ..." part same as the original notation?

Comment: the original notation is $k$ vectors (not in $\mathbb{R}$), the other map is the dot product of those vectors, (in $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: The point is that the first cannot map to $\mathbb{R}$, the "or we could have" is an alternative that would map to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $V$ has some dimension $n$. $V^k$ is a set of $k$ vectors, each with $n$ components.  That's exactly what is written when it says $a: V^k \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: I thought that if $a:V^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$; $x\mapsto y$, then we would have to have $x\subseteq V^k$ and $y\subseteq\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Dansmith: Yes, except you're using the wrong notation: $\subseteq$ means "subset of", whereas the correct statement is that $x\in V^k$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ ("element of").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that notation.

$a:V^k\to\mathbb R$ means $a$ is a function which takes $k$ vector arguments and returns a real number. $a(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ is just an evaluation of $a$ at $(v_1, \ldots, v_k)\in V^k$, so it's a real number.

Comment: surely $a(v_1,..,v_k)$ has $k$ dimensions

Comment: @Dansmith I'm not sure what's the problem. The only thing I can think of is that you should understand $a(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ is just a shorthand for $a((v_1,\ldots,v_k))$.

Comment: @Dansmith: Think about it this way: $V^k$ is a set. $\mathbb{R}$ is a set. I can make a function named $a$ that takes as input elements of $V^k$ and outputs elements of $\mathbb{R}$. The fact that $a$ applied to a given element $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ is written
$$a(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$$
is irrelevant to the fact that $a(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}$ and that $\mathbb{R}$ is a one-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Definitely understand it more now thanks